# Alias/script to delete all local and remote git branches with a specific prefix

Tags: git, jira, zsh

I would like to delete all local and remote branches with a particular prefix in one go, preferably as a zsh alias/function `delete_branches`. We use JIRA, and prefix every branch name with a JIRA number.

So if my `git branch -a` gives me:

```
1234-branch
1234-review
2345-branch-name
2345-review
master
remotes/origin/1234-branch
remotes/origin/1234-review
remotes/origin/2345-branch-name
remotes/origin/2345-review
remotes/origin/master
```

I want to be able to invoke `delete_branches 1234` and see this output

```
Really delete branches 1234-branch, 1234-review? (y/n)
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what problem you have with your solution?

Comment: Would you like to pay me to program that for you?

Comment: "bonus points" is rude if you're not actually bonusing any points

Comment: @random I wasn't aware you could bonus points. I was just using it as an expression.

Comment: @joran I am not confident on my shell scripting skills, which is why I asked here. I know how to delete branches locally and remotely, but not how to do both in sequence.

Comment: @doublesharp Was my question a poor format for this site? I don't have the skill to do this myself (without a large script in python/ruby), and I thought stack overflow was a good place to learn. I don't have money to pay someone to do it, or I'd post this as an advertisement for freelance work. I've seen many other questions related to needing a git alias, so I don't see how mine is different.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all the local branches based on the regex:

```
git branch -D $(printf "%s\n" $(git branch) | grep 1234)
```

To remove all the remote branches based on the regex:

```
git push origin --delete <branchName>
```

At first you need to run this command for remote branches then for local ones.

Example:

```
$ git branch
  1234-first
  1234-second
  2222-first
  2222-second
* master

$ git branch -D $(printf "%s\n" $(git branch -a) | grep 1234)
Deleted branch 1234-first (was fb4949b).
Deleted branch 1234-second (was fb4949b).

$ git branch
  2222-first
  2222-second
* master
```

Comment: Inconsiderate use of `git branch -D`. Danger!

Comment: Tottaly agree, thank you for your comment

Comment: This is close to what I was wanting, but I'm not sure how to store the branch names in between commands.

Comment: You don't need to do it, at first you run the command to remove remote branches, then you run the command to remove the local branches. When you remove remote branches, git doesn't remove the local ones.